# Possible to animate NSSwitch when changing state programatically?

Tags: swift, macos

I am controlling an NSSwitch state in a function. I declared trigger1ToggleOut outlet earlier, when I trigger the function the switch turns on, but it happens instantly, without the sliding animation.
Is there a way to make it animate? (like you can do with progress indicators)

```
func turnSwitchOn()
    {
      trigger1ToggleOut.state = .on
    }
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Quoting from apple doc "The values off and on indicate that the switch is in the off or on position. The switch treats any value other than off as on. Setting this property through the animator() proxy animates the switch to the new value." I guess that answers your question. Not a mac developer so not adding any code as answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding my comment as answer, Quoting from [apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsswitch/3172699-state)

> The values off and on indicate that the switch is in the off or on
> position. The switch treats any value other than off as on. Setting
> this property through the animator() proxy animates the switch to the
> new value.

So you can change your `turnSwitchOn` method to use `animator() proxy` as shown below

```
    func turnSwitchOn() {
        trigger1ToggleOut.animator().state = .on
    }
```

Here is the **O/P**

[image]

Comment: @moonmonkey have you tried this? isn't your problem solved? are you still facing any issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare switch as -

```
var mySwitch = UISwitch()
```

Setting the switch **on**

```
mySwitch.setOn(true, animated: true)
```

For turning it **off**

```
mySwitch.setOn(false, animated: true)
```

This will animate while changing the state.

Comment: I tried this, but I get Value of type 'NSSwitch' has no member 'setOn'. Is it possible this is only for iOS and not for MacOS?

Comment: Yes, it is for iOS. For MacOS you can use **animator().state**  instead of **state** in your code.

Comment: Thanks, this is it!